# SQL Server: using Temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Would I get the value of temporary table from calling the store procedure?
Since @productTable is a temporary table, can I EXEC [dbo.FindProductTotal] 
and get the value in [dbo.updateProductTotal]?
It does not seem to me it works.  If not, is there a way to get the value
from the result of the first temp table from executing in the 2nd store procedure?  The real coding is more complicated so it's not i didn't know just doing simple insert and update tables.  I need to know if this way of coding would work for my real coding.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.FindProductTotal (@ProductID int)
AS

DECLARE @productTable TABLE (subProductID int, productCode varchar(10), productDesc varchar(25), chargeAmt money)

    insert into @productTable 
    select productID, productCode, productDesc, chargeAmt
    from   product
    where region='CA'

--calculate charge here

    UPDATE @productTable 
    SET chargeAmt = (calculation here)
    where ProductID = @ProductID


ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.updateProductTotal (@ProductID int)
AS

DECLARE @productTable TABLE (subProductID int, productCode varchar(10), productDesc varchar(25), chargeAmt money)

EXEC dbo.FindProductTotal @ProductID = 123456

    UPDATE dbo.Manufacture
    SET    productChgAmt = p.chargeAmt 
    FROM   @productTable p
    WHERE  productID = @ProductID
```

Comment: Those aren't temporary tables.  Those are are table variables.  The two are [significantly different](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server), especially with respect to scope.  While this would work with temporary tables, I don't believe a parent's table variables are accessible from a child's scope.  I believe you're creating two distinct objects here.

Comment: yes you were right. They are tables variables. Is there a way can be suggested to reach the same goal- to call another store procedure and get it's value?

Comment: Well, you could use an actual temporary table declared in the parent.  That seems a bit weird to have a temporary object which might not exist in the child, so you might want to check for that. Or you could pass a [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to the child procedure, and then output it back to the parent in a second table variable defined as output.  Honestly, I haven't written a procedure like this at all; I'm just familiar enough with table variables to know that your method wouldn't work.  There's many ways to do it, just not this one!

Comment: You can pass table variables as parameters just like anything else - try that. I don't see any good reason to split that into two stored procedures. Also, from your example you only care about passing the scalar `chargeAmt`. You don't need a table for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FindProductTotal (@ProductID int)
AS
    IF SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##productTable') IS NULL
    DROP TABLE ##productTable

    CREATE TABLE ##productTable(subProductID int, productCode varchar(10), productDesc varchar(25), chargeAmt money)

    --DECLARE @productTable TABLE (subProductID int, productCode varchar(10), productDesc varchar(25), chargeAmt money)

    insert into ##productTable
    select productID, productCode, productDesc, chargeAmt
    from   product
    where region='CA'

--calculate charge here

    UPDATE ##productTable
    SET chargeAmt = (calculation here)
    where ProductID = @ProductID


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.updateProductTotal (@ProductID int)
AS

EXEC dbo.FindProductTotal @ProductID = 123456

    UPDATE dbo.Manufacture
    SET    productChgAmt = p.chargeAmt 
    FROM   ##productTable p
    WHERE  productID = @ProductID
```

Comment: @angelcake, what will happen if the SP called concurrently by more than one user? I think its not solve the problem if you are going to use this SP for web application.

Comment: @selvaTS when the first sp calls, temp db will drop if it exists and if the second sp  is calling, it will use temp table that is created by first sp....  I'm sure it's better way but I dont have any idea about db structure, I just make it works....

Comment: I thought about later what Selva said about SP called by more than one user at same time.  The front end is Access.  When the OBJECT_ID IS NOT NULL and 2nd user enter different ProductID at the same time with the first user, what will happen using object_id?  It seeems risky because the object_id from the first user would be dropped by the 2nd user.  When the OBJECT_ID IS NULL, does the 2nd user get the same result as the first user because of using same temp table? Then in this case, the result for 2nd user will not be correct.

Comment: so make them one diez like #productTable so it will be user connection level and it will create different temp tables for all users.

Comment: Do you mean instead of using ##, use #?

Comment: yes ##temp = Global temp table #temp = local temp table   @@variable = global variable @variable = local variable  also you can see them  in tempdb  in system databases.  if you use it ##tmp sql server will give a name tmp but if you use it like #tmp sql server will give a name like tmp___________000000001   and for other user tmp___________000000002  you can check all of that tables from tempdb system database.